# Is it a good idea to remove node.js layer while working with the application having Angular in front end and Java in the backend?

Tags: java, angularjs, node.js

I am working on the application which has the requirements from the Architect to use node.js as a proxy layer between front end and back end. Front end is AngularJS, backend is Java and server is Tomcat. Web services are restful with json data exchange format. Application might have many concurrent user.

My idea is to remove the node.js layer and package front and back end under the same root rather than deploying separately. I want to allow angular to communicate with back end directly with HTTP calls.

Before stepping in to that move , i want to know that what would be the consequences and how those can be handled ?

Comment: what does the node.js layer actually do, according to the Architect?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should ask your Architect what is he planning? 
Maybe there are some requirements you don't know?

Proxy is in some cases are very useful

Answer (score 0):

You can replace node.js with java nio to support many concurrent users.

In java 8 you can use avatar-js to embed node.js inside java.
[Avatar-js java](https://avatar-js.java.net/)